# Is there a single verb for 'to make positive'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What SINGLE verb means 'to make or turn positive (something)'? Urbandictionary.com contains [positify](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=positify), but I prefer a verb accepted by a worthy dictionary like the OED.
I seek only 1  SINGLE verb; please exclude phrasal verbs or verb phrases.

Also, what of 'to make or turn something negative'? The transitive verb ['negative'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/negative) doesn't mean this; it has 2 different definitions (first, to reject'; second, 'to neutralise').

Some sample sentences of my own:

1. I wish to learn how to **make positive** [clauses of negative polarity](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12619/5609).

2. How can we **make** negative comments (or experiences) **positive**?

Comment: What do you mean by "something"? And what do you mean by "positive"? Can asparagus be positive?

Comment: @TimRomano Given his posting history here and [on other stacks in the exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12619/5609), he's likely looking for a concise way to express "*turning a double-negative statement into a positive assertion*". That is, make a logical proposition positive grammatically/semantically. As in *negate*, but strictly in one direction.

Comment: The negative word would be _negate_. I'm not aware of a positive version of that.

Comment: Could you show the context where you would use this word?

Comment: @Dan Bron: The antonym of *negate* when what is being negated is a negation?

Comment: @Barmar Negate means "flip the logical sense, toggle". It doesn't mean "*make negative*". If you *negate* `-5` you get `5`, a positive number. If you *Johnny doesn't like apples*, you get *Johnny likes apples*, a positive statement. I can't speak for him, but my guess is LePress is looking for is a word which describes what I just did to the sentence about Johnny, but could *not* describe the inverse (turning *does* into *doesn't*). Check out the link in my previous comment for more context & examples.

Comment: @TimRomano See my previous comment addressed to Barmar.

Comment: @Barmar It would be closed on Linguistics as specific to English (they'd tell him to migrate it here). Maybe Philosophy.SE? But saying it requires a technical term presupposes it doesn't have a generic English term like *negate*, which is the question itself, I suppose.

Comment: @DanBron et al. above: I just edited my OP to exemplify. Better? 'Dan Bron': Thanks for citing that question; I linked to it now.

Comment: Maybe "improve" or "turn around" negative comments. For "clauses of negative polarity", negating them make them positive.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Unary Positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Unary_operation#Unary_negative_and_positive)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch +1. Thanks for introducing me to that term. Yes; I think so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OED* gives ***[positivize](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/265739?redirectedFrom=positivize#eid)***:

> *trans.* To render positive or real.